# Playback of music files a little distorted after downloading Audactiy on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, snap, audacity

I attempted to do some editing of an mp3 music file using Audacity on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04).

I downloaded Audacity and did the editing. Afterwards, when I played back my file it was a little distorted. I tried the file on another machine and it was fine. Downloading Audacity  has done something weird to the sound playback on my laptop.

I have uninstalled Audacity but the problem persists. When downloading, I was advised to run `sudo snap connect audacity:alsa` in my terminal. Could this have messed anything up?

Comment: I did some digging and found this : https://www.linux.org/threads/audacity-isnt-working-properly.33201/  Read through it and see if anything helps isolate the issue.  As for the command you ran: this thread provides an answer https://github.com/diddlesnaps/audacity/issues/29  Based on what I read there it shouldn't have messed anything up unless there's something already amiss before you ran it.  Check bug reports in Launchpad as well.

Comment: Did you restarted your machine? Could you provide the output of `journalctl -xe -p warning | grep -i audio` and `inxi --audio`? Does this happen with any audio file of any format? Try with `cvlc --verbose 1 myoudiofile`

Comment: It seems you installed the snap. You could try:
1) `sudo apt install audacity`.
2) another player, like `audacious`.
3) reinstalling the snap, and `sudo snap connect audacity:pulseaudio`.

Comment: Did you manage to try any of what was suggested?
Feedback is essential.